# HashMap One key associated to a list

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap

I have a list of objects that contain row data for a table. There are multiple columns in that table but I don't think that's an issue. The logic I need to apply would require only two columns. These two columns are known as  **Chemical Name**  and  **Batch Number** . Now the interesting part here is that a chemical can occur many times for a particular batch number. For example,

### CHEMICAL | BATCH | OTHER COLUMNS

### A----------------100---------ABC

### A----------------100---------GHF

### A----------------100---------GHL

Now what I need is the batch number and its associated rows. I realized that the best way to do this would be HashMap where K is Batch number and V is a List. Now I am not sure how to assign a Key to a List containing row objects.

I wish but I cannot do this at the database level so that is out of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could just use guava library. There is [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) class(technically interface) to fit your need: One key mapping to multiple values.

You might first get all your `Row` objects in a list, then use the `Multimaps.index` method to create a `Multimap` instance. [Multimaps](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html) is a util class which provide a lot of methods to create a `Multimap` instance.

Your code maybe looks like:

```
List<Row> rows = ... // all the row objects.
Multimap<String, Row> rowsMap = Multimaps.index(rows, new Function<Row, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(Row row) {
        return row.getRowKey(); // assume that getRowKey() return the key of one row.
    }
});
```

See more details from guava api.

Comment: Tried MultiMap from Apache Collections and it worked. But thanks a lot man and thanks to everyone on here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Map<String, List<String>>` to store a list of things against a given key.

If you want to get fancy, you could use this [anonymous](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) implementation:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>() {

    public List<String> get(Object key) {
        List<String> list = super.get(key);
        if (list == null) { 
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            put(key, list);
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

which will automatically create a list when one doesn't yet exist, so you can safely use it like this:

```
map.get(key).add("new item"); // won't get a NuilPointerException
```

If find this code pattern of a customer `get()` method very handy!

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Row` object to hold your values, and then add a `List<Row>` to your map:

```
Map<String, List<Row>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Row>>();
List<Row> list = new ArrayList<Row>();
list.add(new Row(...));
list.add(new Row(...));
map.put("someKey", list);
```

If you need to do it in a loop, you'd use the following:

```
Map<String, List<Row>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Row>>();
for (Row currentRow : rows) {
    String key = currentRow.getKey();
    List<Row> rows = map.get(key);
    if (rows == null) {
      rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
    }
    rows.add(currentRow);
    map.put(key, rows);
}
```